# How to Import downloaded Laravel Project into Xamp Locally

Tags: php, laravel, import

I am new to Laravel framework and  on that I need help.

I downloaded Laravel project for my own practice, I extracted it and pasted all the files to the htdocs folder under the folder lara, This project has a setup for installation and I followed the flow of that to install, i.e. it asked me my database name so i created a database in my phpamydmin with the name laravelP and put localhost in the setup and name of the project. After these information the project is installed and when i hit on the link

http://localhost/lara

It shows absolutely fine the login things,

Is this a correct way to import any laravel project into xamp? I saw so many tutorials on it and every one is using different methods plus on that when i run different command showing in those tutorials accordingly but it didn't show me the result instead of that it shows me the error. Image in of that:

[image]

as i am adding any files laravel routes and placing things still it giving me any error "It just shows me that 'Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.'"

Comment: Follow these steps: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation Downloading is not an easy way to run Laravel.

Comment: sir i want to import a laravel project locally! i need to know this procedure and techniques for my future practice

Comment: I use xampp as well and haven't run into any issues. You either use php artisan serve or xampp. Not both

Comment: sir i am running the xamp things and it is running fine! my question is this a correct way to run a laravel project because after when i am running any comands it is reponding me with the error on cmd

Comment: @AbdulRafay the installer doesn't have any binaries or anything. It's pure PHP. The installer will download the files and install the vendors along with generate encryption keys. You install the installer with composer then use `laravel new appname` forever. That is how it is done, locally and on a production server from scratch

Comment: Okay, if you have it installed correctly then you need to go to localhost/project_name/public

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the following instructions below.

1. Verify that you have installed composer at your xamp PHP directory.
2. Copy the laravel project in htdocs
3. Setup env file i-e create DB and put credentials in this file
4. run command ' composer install '  to install all dependencies for this laravel project.
5. run command ' php artisan migrate ' to buildup DB schema if project has migrations.
6. run command ' php artisan db:seed ' to seed up the DB if there are seeders for this project.
7. run command ' php artisan serve ' and visit url http://localhost:8080

All is done!

Answer (score 0):

the best way is, used laravel and run it through php artisan cmd, don't need to paste in hotdocs.

1. download and install laravel
2. make changes in env for db connection
3. start using `php artisan serve`
4. project start